# How to play local video files in a browser

Tags: android

Am looking for the way to play video inside my android browser locally. There may be two or more video's in a local page (like facebook contains video's).
Can anyone please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually reading about the specifics of the Android built in browser I would safely say, you can't. Well, if you run a local html file it might work, but if you intend to have an external page from which you can play local videos it shouldn't work. I say shouldn't because in the early days of browsers some of them actually did give you access to the local file system. Javascript for example could use `file://`, something I used myself for image previewing before upload. But this was a major security concern and all modern browsers prevent this.

The difference is if you run a local file or a file on your own local web server. Since then, your local file system is actually part of the web servers file system and the web server can serve your local files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Alternative to this I have also tried to play .swf files locally (from asset andsdcard both) but no luck..Is it possible to play local swf files or not??? Can u  pls guide me..

Comment: The same principle applies to all local files. Be it flash, videos, text or images.

Comment: yes u r absolutely right.SWF Video and all other video are working well. But am facing one problem whenever am scrolling my webpage upwards, the video content present in webview is getting overlap with title bar. If u say I will send u screenshot just gimme ur mail address so that I can revert you @inquam